# Cant upload files to Google Drive

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, google-drive-api

The code works locally but when I tried to deploy the website and tried to run it, it throws an exception:

> *Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"Class not registered","ExceptionType":"System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception","StackTrace":"
>   at
>   Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.d__1.MoveNext()
>   in
>   c:\code\google.com\google-api-dotnet-client\default_182\Tools\Google.Apis.Release\bin\Debug\output\default\Src\GoogleApis.Auth.DotNet4\OAuth2\GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.cs:line
>   59*

Here is the code:

```
UserCredential credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                new ClientSecrets
                {
                    ClientId = Settings.ClientId,
                    ClientSecret = Settings.ClientSecret,
                },
                new[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive },
                   "user",
                   CancellationToken.None,
                   new FileDataStore("MyStore")).Result;

            var service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = "AppName",
            });


            File body = new File();
            body.Title = fileName;
            body.Description = "Body";
            body.MimeType = "text/plain";

            String dir = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data");

            byte[] byteArray = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);
            System.IO.MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(byteArray);

            FilesResource.InsertMediaUpload request = service.Files.Insert(body, stream, "text/plain");

            request.Upload();
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE:

I tried to change the code to this:

```
var token = new TokenResponse { RefreshToken = "1/0i6iw4nsecXSVn1_OtYZVo7VCs24jKXdji6gVBrz3TM" };
                var credential = new UserCredential(new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow(new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer
                 {
                     ClientSecrets = new ClientSecrets
                     {
                         ClientId = Settings.ClientId,
                         ClientSecret = Settings.ClientSecret
                     },
                     Scopes = new[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive },
                     DataStore = new FileDataStore("MyStore")
                 }), "user", token);
```

It doesn't throw exception but the file won't upload. The MyStore folder was created though. Am I missing something? I also tried to implement the code posted here http://www.daimto.com/google-oauth2-csharp/ but it's also not working.

Comment: I think your missing some dlls,  I would also be interested in hearing if you are able to use it using FileDataStore, I have wondered if the web-server could handle it.

Comment: But when I uploaded the files to server all the dlls were transferred. I still have no clue what went wrong. Do you know a better code that works?

Comment: I used your code posted here http://www.daimto.com/google-oauth2-csharp/ but it's not working and the data store folder is not even created

Answer (score 0):

**First:**

`'Class not registered'` implies to me that its an issue with the dlls.  Check your machine vs the server are the .dll in GAC?  No I'm not sure if they need to be in GAC or not I haven't tested it I'm guessing.  I almost remember having an issue with that, but it was a while ago.   How about the .net version on the server?  again another guess.

**Second:**

Your code is calling `FileDataStore` which will look in `%appData%` for something like this.  Note: `-user` on the end of the file name is the same as the `"user"` you sent.  So your are telling it to look for the file in that directory with that name.

> %appData%\MyStore\Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Responses.TokenResponse-user

The problem you are having may be that its a webserver the server may not have access to create the files, but I am no webserver expert you might want to try consulting your web server admin.

I personally recommend that you create your own implementation of `IDataStore`, I would rather have the `refreshTokens` stored in the database associated with the users account.   If you decide to do this you will be able to feed it the `refreshToken` like this:

```
//Now we load our saved refreshToken.
StoredResponse myStoredResponse = new StoredResponse(_RefreshToken);
```

// Now we pass a SavedDatastore with our StoredResponse.

```
var credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
              new ClientSecrets { ClientId = "YourClientId", ClientSecret = "YourClientSecret" },
              new[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive,
                DriveService.Scope.DriveFile },
              "user",
              CancellationToken.None,
               new SavedDataStore(myStoredResponse)).Result; }
```

Notice how I used new `SavedDataStore(myStoredResponse)` and not `new FileDataStore("MyStore")`. The tutorial has an example of how to create `SavedDataStore`.   The code for that is a little long to post here.

Note there is a sample project at the bottom of that tutorial run it.  Yes I admit its a little confusing, I should update that sample project.
**Third**

I don't understand your update code.  I don't think you can create your own `UserCredential`.  `UserCredential` is returned by `GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync` after it has gotten you an new `AccessToken`.  It gets you a new `AccessToken` by either requested access from the user or useing the `RefreshToken` it already has to get you a new one.   So unless you have already gotten your own `AccessToken` manually or something I don't see how this will be a valid `UserCredential` that you could use.

Fourth:

I think you are either under pressure from above, or you have been looking at this two long.  Take a step back, your update makes me think your desperate and grasping at straws.  Free to email me if you still can't get it working.

If you do get it working with the help of your server admin using fileDatastore I would love to know that as well for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

"Class not registered" is actually because the authentication code is trying to start your web browser but fails because of a bug in Chrome when running in elevated mode.

Read the details in my [google-api-dotnet-client bug report](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/detail?id=529&sort=-id&colspec=ID%20Type%20Component%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary).

Workaround is to NOT run code or Visual Studio as Administrator, or make modification in source. Reinstalling Chrome might also help.